# Validating Contact Number in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a textbox and a div in my form like this :

```
<input type="text" name="NContact" placeholder="New Contact No." id="txtNewContact"/>
<div id="divCheckContact">
```

Now on every key press of a key in NContact I need to check if the value entered is a number or not and also it is 10 digit number.And display message in the divison

How to do it Please help.

Comment: What have you tired? Have you searched for other questions? Do you have any experience in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `pattern` and `title` to do this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{10}" title="Type 10 digits please" />
```

The above will check for 10 digit number and if it isn't valid the title will be displayed.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/PJnQF/)

**Note:** This is part of html5 spec. Will not work for IE 9 and below.

You can also do it in pure js:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('txtNewContact'); 
elem.onkeydown = function(){
   if(!/\d{10}/.test(elem.value)){
     alert("Type 10 digits please");
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for HTML5 version and alternative Javascript version.

Answer (score 0):

use this

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tsZSN/2/)

```
$('#txtNewContact').keyup(function(){

      var re = isNaN($(this).val());
      if(!re)
         {
 $('#divCheckContact').html("");         
         }else
         {
             $('#divCheckContact').html("please enter only numbers");
             $(this).val('');
         }

      if($(this).val().length>10)
      {
          $('#divCheckContact').html("please enter only ten 10 digits contact no");

      return false;
      } 

  });
```